# Maintaining Session across different domains with Azure Redis Cache Session State Provider

Tags: asp.net, session, azure, redis

How can i share the same session state across different web apps using Azure Redis Cache Session State Provider?

My Web.configs for both applications are like that:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySessionStateStore"
            type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
            port="6380"
            host="[myhostname].redis.cache.windows.net"
            accessKey="[mykey]"
            throwOnError="true"
            applicationName="[mySharedAppName]"
            ssl="true" />
      </providers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are typically two things you need to do:

1. Set the `applicationName` attribute to the same string value in the web.config of both apps.
2. If the apps are in different IIS sites or different servers, you may need to change the [cookie scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sectionToggle5) for the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie that ASP.NET sends to the browser for you behind the scenes. You'll get into trouble if the scope of that session cookie doesn't encompass both apps: the web browsers will use different session cookies and your sessions won't be shared. But if you just have two app directories under the same site then you shouldn't need to think about this.